# React-router redirects changes URL but doesn't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I've been struggling for quite a while on a feature I'd like to implement.

When a user login, I'd like to redirect them to the homepage.
I am using an action for my route '/account/login', which is correctly called upon form submission and actually does logs my user in if the credentials were valid.

Upon successful connection, this action returns `redirect('/')` from `react-router-dom`.
Then, the URL is correctly changed from `'localhost:3000/account/login'` to `'localhost:3000'`, yet my homepage is not rendered and the Login form stays there.

Do note that **I have tried redirecting to other URL** from my website, such as `"/profile"`, yet the result was always the same: the URL would get updated, but the Login form would stay instead of the expected page being rendered.

Below is what I believe to be the relevant portion of my code:

file index.js

```
import useAuth, { AuthProvider } from "./bridge/AuthProvider";

const apiClient = createApiClient();
const router = (authContext) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Root />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      id: "root",
      children: [
        {
          errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
          children: [
            {
              index: true,
              element: <Home />,
            },
            {
              path: "account/login",
              action: authContext.login,
              element: <LoginPage />,
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

function RenderRoot() {
  const auth = useAuth();
  return <RouterProvider router={router(auth)} />;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider apiClient={apiClient}>
      <RenderRoot />
    </AuthProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

File AuthProvider.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = React.createContext({});

export function AuthProvider({ children, apiClient }) {
  const [identity, setIdentity] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      if (typeof config.data === FormData) {
        let object = {};
        config.data.forEach((value, key) => (object[key] = value));
        config.data = JSON.stringify(object);
      }
      return config;
    });

    const responseInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
      (res) => {
        return res;
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err.status == 401 || err.status == 403) {
          setIdentity({});
          return redirect("/account/login");
        }
        console.err("rejecting response ", err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      console.error("Ejecting intercepts");
      apiClient.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      apiClient.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [apiClient]);

  // Action of /account/login
  // Reset identity and Send username and password to the server.
  async function login({ request, params }) {
    try {
      setIdentity({});
      const formData = await request.formData();
      const body = Object.fromEntries(formData);
      const res = await apiClient.post("/api/auth/login", body);
      if (res.data && typeof res.data === "object") {
        let newIdentity = {};
        if ("univID" in res.data) newIdentity.univID = res.data.univID;
        if ("email" in res.data) newIdentity.email = res.data.email;
        if ("id" in res.data) newIdentity.id = res.data.id;

        if (newIdentity?.univID || newIdentity?.email || newIdentity?.id)
          setIdentity(newIdentity);
      }
      return redirect("/");
    } catch (error) {
      return error.response;
    }
  }

  const context = {
    login,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

File account.jsx

```
export function LoginPage() {
  const [valids, setValids] = useState({
    univID: true,
    password: true,
  });

  const err = useActionData ();
  
  if (err !== undefined) {
    if (err.status == 401 && err.data.errors !== undefined) {
      setValids({
        univID: !("univID" in err.data.errors),
        password: !("password" in err.data.errors),
      });
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Relevant packages versions are:

```json
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.11.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic issue really is the `identity` state. By declaring this state in the `AuthProvider` component it couples the `apiClient` and the `login` action function to be internal dependencies. I suggest lifting the `identity` state up to the parent `App` component and pass it down to the `router` object. Instead of a full-blown `AuthProvider` component you'll create an `AuthLayout` component to run the side-effect to stand up and tear down the Axios interceptors and use the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function. The `login` action will be declared separately on its own and passed the `setIdentity` state updater function and be able to use the `redirect` utility function.

Example:

login

```js
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// Action of /account/login
// Reset identity and Send username and password to the server.
export const login = ({
  apiClient,
  setIdentity
}) => async ({ request, params }) => {
  try {
    setIdentity({});

    const formData = await request.formData();
    const body = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    const res = await apiClient.post("/api/auth/login", body);

    if (res.data && typeof res.data === "object") {
      let newIdentity = {};
      if ("univID" in res.data) newIdentity.univID = res.data.univID;
      if ("email" in res.data) newIdentity.email = res.data.email;
      if ("id" in res.data) newIdentity.id = res.data.id;

      if (newIdentity?.univID || newIdentity?.email || newIdentity?.id)
        setIdentity(newIdentity);
    }
    return redirect("/");
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};
```

AuthLayout.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthLayout = ({ apiClient, setIdentity }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      if (typeof config.data === FormData) {
        let object = {};
        config.data.forEach((value, key) => (object[key] = value));
        config.data = JSON.stringify(object);
      }
      return config;
    });

    const responseInterceptor = apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
      (res) => {
        return res;
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          setIdentity({});
          return navigate("/account/login", { replace: true });
        }
        console.err("rejecting response ", err);
        return Promise.reject(err);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      console.error("Ejecting intercepts");
      apiClient.interceptors.request.eject(requestInterceptor);
      apiClient.interceptors.response.eject(responseInterceptor);
    };
  }, [apiClient, navigate, setIdentity]);

  return <Outlet />;
};
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";

const apiClient = createApiClient();

const router = ({ apiClient, setIdentity }) =>
  createBrowserRouter([
    {
      element: (
        <AuthLayout
          apiClient={apiClient}
          setIdentity={setIdentity} 
        />
      ),
      children: [
        {
          path: "/",
          element: <Root />,
          errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
          id: "root",
          children: [
            {
              errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
              children: [
                { index: true, element: <Home /> },
                {
                  path: "account/login",
                  action: login({ apiClient, setIdentity }),
                  element: <LoginPage />
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]);

export default function RenderRoot() {
  const [identity, setIdentity] = useState({});

  return (
    <RouterProvider
      router={router({ identity, setIdentity, apiClient })}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this doesn't work as I get a warning a call to useNavigate isn't valid outside any Router context. This might not be relevant, but using useActionData() in LoginPage, after a call to AuthProvider.login always return undefined.

Comment: @vultkayn Oops, yes, you are quite right, I see that now. Give me a couple minutes to update my answer with a fix.

Comment: @vultkayn Ah, you know what, I think I misread what your code was actually trying to do. It has some logic that comprises the action, and the other is internal React component logic. I'll have to think about this a bit more how to split the logic in a sane manner.

Comment: I did some more testing. By changing the action of `account/login` to a dummy function `() => {console.debug ("login action"); return redirect('/');},`, I do observe the expected/correct behavior upon submission of the form.

Comment: @vultkayn Yeah, I don't doubt a standalone inline action function works. I've updated my answer and tried to explain what the conflicting issue is between having the `identity` state ***and*** and `login` action ***in*** the same React context provider component ***and*** needing the routing context all at the same time.